# Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation. Error

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am stuck in a situation here. I am getting an error like this.

```
 compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'LoginComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at compiler.es5.js:15595
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15577)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26965)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26938)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26867)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4522)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
```

My Login Component Looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/Core';

@Component({
    selector:'login-component',
    templateUrl:'./login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent{}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './main/app.component';

import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I got this error when I try to import LoginComponent into declaration. Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a typo in the import in your `LoginComponent`'s file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/Core';
```

It's lowercase `c`, not uppercase

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: i have used lowercase still same issue

Comment: "Component" with capital case C is mandatory now. Small case not allowed.

Comment: @Praveen Patel What? Decorator `Component` never had lowercase **c**

Comment: I don't know in past versions, I am using Angular 10. In this it will through error if it is in small case.

Answer (score 94):

Not a solution to the concrete example above, but there may be many reasons why you get this error message. I got it when I accidentally added a shared module to the module declarations list and not to imports.

In app.module.ts:

```
import { SharedModule } from './modules/shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     // Should not have been added here...
  ],
  imports: [
     SharedModule
  ],
```

Comment: Similarly, I got this error when I had accidentally pasted the name of one of my Angular app's services into the `declarations` array. (It should have only been in the `providers` array further down in the file.)

Answer (score 21):

If you are exporting another class in that module, make sure that it is not in between `@Component` and your `ClassComponent`. For example:

```
@Component({ ... })

export class ExampleClass{}

export class ComponentClass{}  --> this will give this error.
```

**FIX:**

```
export class ExampleClass{}

@Component ({ ... })

export class ComponentClass{}
```

Answer (score 11):

You get this error when you wrongly add shared service to "declaration" in your appmodules instead of adding it to "provider".

Comment: If you get this when doing shallow testing of spec.ts files in angular, this is the correct answer! check your imports, for me it was the RouterTestingModule in the declarations instead of imports!

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I accidentally added the package in the declaration but it should be in imports.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is below way and It was my fault that when happened I put `HomeService` in **declaration section** in `app.module.ts` whereas I should put `HomeService` in **Providers section** that as you see below `HomeService` in `declaration:[]` is not in a correct place and  `HomeService` is in `Providers :[]` section in a correct place that should be.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component'; 
import { HomeService } from './components/home/home.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,  
    HomeService // You will get error here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HomeService // Right place to set HomeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a component declared without the styleUrls property, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
```

instead of:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./server.component.css']
})
```

Adding in the styleUrls property solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error when I used another class instead of component down the component decorator.

> Component class must come just after the component decorator

```
  @Component({
 selector: 'app-smsgtrecon',
 templateUrl: './smsgtrecon.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./smsgtrecon.component.css'],
 providers: [ChecklistDatabase]
 })


// THIS CAUSE ISSUE MOVE THIS UP TO COMPONENT DECORATOR
/**
* Node for to-do item
*/
 export class TodoItemNode {
 children: TodoItemNode[];
 item: string;
}


 export class SmsgtreconComponent implements OnInit {
```

After moving TodoItemNode to the top of component decorator it worked

**Solution**

```
// THIS CAUSE ISSUE MOVE THIS UP TO COMPONENT DECORATOR
/**
* Node for to-do item
*/
 export class TodoItemNode {
 children: TodoItemNode[];
 item: string;
}


@Component({
 selector: 'app-smsgtrecon',
 templateUrl: './smsgtrecon.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./smsgtrecon.component.css'],
 providers: [ChecklistDatabase]
 })


 export class SmsgtreconComponent implements OnInit {
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I mistakenly added this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-item',
    templateUrl: './some-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-item.component.scss'],
    providers: [ConfirmationService]
})

declare var configuration: any;
```

while the correct form is:

```
declare var configuration: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-item',
    templateUrl: './some-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-item.component.scss'],
    providers: [ConfirmationService]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I mistakenly added a service to the declarations section in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

The Above error occurs if any wrong import done.
For example sometimes Service files may be added in TestBed.configureTestingModule.
And also while importing Material component for example import from

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog'
```

not from

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material'
```

Comment: Format your answer

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use **BrowserModule** in a shared module (import and export). That was not allowed so instead I had to use the **CommonModule** instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I hate this, but restarting `ng serve` worked for me. It might be because I created new folders and files in my project, and angular-cli did not detect them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons is exporting your component from ts file that doesn't have `.component`. suffix.
file name should be `component-name.component.ts`.
`component-name.ts` will produce this error

Answer (score 1):

****TLDR**; The service or module should go in `imports`**

---

In my case, the issue occurred only when running tests, as I accidentally added my module in `declaration **but it should be in imports**. Instead of this:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent, MyCustomModule],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Changed to this:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [MyCustomModule]
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```